# Activate windows 10 after re-installing (I have lost my product key)

Tags: windows-10, reinstall, windows-activation, product-key

I own a Lenovo T430 laptop. In 2017, I installed Windows 10 using my original Windows 7 product key. Unfortunately, I cannot find that product key anymore. I need to re-install windows 10. Will it be automatically activated after the installation, if I skip the step of asking the product key during the installation?

In my opinion, I believe that my laptop will have a digital entitlement stored on the Microsoft Activation Servers and this will not be a problem. Is that true?

If not, please suggest me a solution or a workaround.

Comment: Yes, it should automatically activate if you install the same version of windows. When it prompts for a key, just skip. Do note, you can also choose to reset your pc which reinstalls windows 10 from within windows 10. In that case it will not even ask for a key and skip the entire setup screens. It will only ask if you want to keep files and settings, or go fully clean. Just search for reset pc in the start menu. Also, it may not work if you change hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the hardware matches, then Windows 10 should activate automatically after a few days.  MS keeps a massive database of all PCs that have activated Windows 10, with unique hashes for the motherboard, processor, and possibly other components.  If you keep all the same hardware, it should match without any effort on your part.

Comment: There are no hardware changes on my device. Thank you.